# Recommended approach when looping through and assigning values to the same field over and over again in c#

Tags: c#, variables, memory, field

To start off with a disclaimer, this is not one of the typical stack overflow questions where I am stuck but instead I have some working code so I really appreciate to seek some advice on the best approach here.
Take the code below

```
Student student;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    //SetToDefault();
    student = GetStudent(i);
}

Student GetStudent(int id)
{
    if (id == 1)
    {
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.name = "Jeff";
        return stu;
    }

    else if (id == 2)
    {
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.name = "Mark";
        return stu;
    }

    else if (id == 3)
    {
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.name = "Dave";
        return stu;
    }

    return new Student();
}

void SetToDefault()
{
    student = null;
}
```

the Class Student :

```
public class Student
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I have field of type student, followed by a loop which will return a student based on a certain ID and assign it to this field. See the problem I have is, when the loop goes through its first iteration the value of the field is null (since nothing has been assigned yet) but of course when ID is 1, a student with name "Jeff" is returned. Now when the second iteration is executed, the field student is not null, it has the previous student still stored and what it will do is sort of override the field when the student with ID 2, is resolved ("Mark" to be preside) and this will continue to go on.

My question is, is this bad or can some exception be thrown because the value of the same field gets overridden several times?
If this is bad, is executing the commented method SetToDefault(); a better approach as it will set the field to null before assigning a new value to it?

appreciate your time!

Comment: What is the point of creating and discarding 9 instances of `Student` ? Is it bad?? Possibly, but it is certainly useless and pointless.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield are you saying explicitly calling a SetToDefault(); type of method is point less?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between assigning 'null' to the field in each iteration, and assigning the next value (without assigning null first).

keep in mind that the 'student' variable is simply a pointer to an object, so overriding its value simply means the you're storing another pointer in it, while all the other 'Students' remain on the heap (until garbage collection).

**"is this bad or can some exception be thrown because the value of the same field gets overridden several times?"**

an exception will never be thrown for overriding a variable multiple times, the languages doesn't "care" as long as there is enough memory available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate a bit more on what "as there is enough memory available." means

Comment: Your process "asks" from your OS (operating system) for memory allocations every time you create a new object, your program might run into a situation where it asks the OS to allocate X bytes memory for a new object, but there isn't enough free memory for that object (either its too large or your free memory is fully used).

NOTE: it's an extremely rare situtaion, but in the case mentioned above, an `OutOfMemoryException` will be thrown